# DISTINCT for Grouped ROWS in POWER BI (DAX)

Tags: group-by, powerbi, combinations, distinct, dax

I had a TABLE

> `ID  TYPES
>   1   A         \\
>   1   B         \\
>   2   B         \\
>   3   A         \\
>   4   A         \\
>   4   A          \\
>   4   A          \\
>   4   C          \\
>   4   D           \\
>   4   E           \\
>   5   B           \\
>   5   B           \\
>   6   A           \\
>   7   A           \\
>   7   B           \\
>   7   C           \\
>   8   B           \\
>   8   B           \\
>   9   D           \\
>   10  A           \\
>   10  A           \\
>   10  D`

I have TABLE:

> `ID  TYPES
>
>   1   A+B         \\
>   2   B           \\
>   3   A           \\
>   4   A+A+A+C+D+E \\
>   5   B+B         \\
>   6   A           \\
>   7   A+B+C       \\
>   8   B+B         \\
>   9   D           \\
>   10  A+A+D`

It was used: 
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("c:\Desktop\stac.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"TYPE", type text}, {"ID", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1",{{"ID", type text}, {"TYPE", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"All Rows", each *, type table [ID=text, TYPE=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "Custom", each [All Rows][TYPE]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(*, Text.From), "+"), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"All Rows"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

But I need to distinct values:

> `ID  TYPES
>
>   1   A+B         \\
>   2   B           \\
>   3   A           \\
>   4   A+C+D+E \\
>   5   B        \\
>   6   A           \\
>   7   A+B+C       \\
>   8   B        \\
>   9   D           \\
>   10  A+D`

Comment: Please add some sample data (minimal example) with your starting data and what you try to achieve (in a table like structure).

Comment: I tried to retype and reformat example.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub Thank you for your answer very much. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first step group your table in the query designer by `ID` and `Types`. So your table would become from this

```
ID   Types
1     A         
1     B  
1     B         
2     B         
3     A        
4     A        
4     A         
4     A
```

to this:

```
ID   Types
1     A         
1     B         
2     B         
3     A                
4     A
```

Then apply the same step as you did in your code above to combine the different types in one column:

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(, Text.From), "+"), type text})
```

Comment: Great advice, thank you very much. Firstly I grouped data, then used them as new source, last I applicated functional code and it work great now!! I still cant upvote for you but I will and then give you that.